# Reload offset cached pages of ViewPager to refesh content

Tags: android, caching, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've implemented a night mode view on my app that uses Fragments and ViewPager using only a webview that loads an HTML content. Now on button click I triggered the night mode via Javascript and store the configuration on my shared preference as a new settings. The night mode should be implemented across all the fragment pages in the viewPager but this doesn't work on the cached pages as it still uses the old configuration unless they are destroyed on scrolling.

I wonder if there's anyway I can reload the webView content of those cached pages on my viewPager so that everything will use a same formatting. I tried to notifyDataSetChanged but this doesn't work as I expected and I guess this is not the correct way to do it as I may lose the current position I am in.

Is theres any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use BroadcastReceiver receiver for each fragment.

**EDIT**

In each fragment of your viewpager:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("eventName"));
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDetach();
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Refresh fragment here as you want
    }
};
```

And then on Button click call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("eventName");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Other way is to save fragments instance of viewpager.